# Sidebar height equal to Main Content area

Tags: css, height, sidebar, fluid

my problem is that I want to have the color of the **#promocion** area (where the hands animation show) to be equal in **height** to my Main content area (**Fluid**, kinda new here and don't know how to do this).

I try to do a height 100% in #promocion but doesn't work in **IE**...

[Check out my CSS & website just a sec...](http://arojas.dinterweb.com/colono/departamentos.php)

**Thank you** for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite method for this is still [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) at [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com). Holy Grail seems like overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [holy grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail) of layouts.  [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) will be a great resource for not only the hows but also for the whys.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can accomplish this.  You can do it with some basic Javascript. You can also try the "Faux Columns" approach, although I am not a huge fan of the technique myself.